# CSS - Dynamically change font-size to fit container's height

Tags: css, flexbox, font-size

I have a text in a flex container that I want to have constant height (`10vh`). As the viewport is getting more narrow, the text (initially single line) starts row wrapping and overflowing.

What's the best way to decrease the font size to make sure the text always occupies a fixed portion of the `vh`? I'm fine with the text wrapping, in fact I'd even prefer it to wrap in narrow viewports.

```html
<div id="logo">
   <img src="./img/logo.ico" />
   <p id="title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
</div>
```

```css
#title{
font-size: 6vh;
}
#logo {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 10vh;
}
```

the font-size can't be fixed on `vh`, because it needs to decrease only after wrapping. `vw` makes even less sense, beucase the font will be resizing constantly on any `vw` change

Comment: you can demonstrate your code using `Javascript/HTML/CSS snippet`

Comment: For that purpose use `media-quires`